# Mimic the browser back button - Barbajs

Tags: javascript

Using Barbajs - how can I get my app back buttons working like the browser back button using the History Manager?

Navigation flow example:

Home > Notifications > Post

By clicking back I want

Post > Notifications > Home

Mimicking the browser back button.

At the moment I am using

`PrevLink.href = Barba.HistoryManager.prevStatus().url;`

However this leaves me in an endless loop:

Post > Notifications > Post > Notifications > Post > Notifcations ect

I know `Barba.HistoryManager.history;` has an array of all my URL’s but how can I go back from this:

- Home
- Notifications
- Post

If I go back from Post, then I have 4 in the array and I'm not sure how to get to Home.

- Home
- Notifications
- Post
- Notifications

Thanks

Comment: When you go back set a state in your history manager, something like `HistoryManager.wentBack = true` then on page load instead of pushing the page into history, remove the previous last page.

Comment: Thank you, I ended up solving this not using History manager but simply javascript:history.back()

Comment: That's great, you ought to answer your question with your solution. Never know who you might help!

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this not using History manager but simply javascript:history.back()